# Bag of Words with Negative Words in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I have this document

It is not normal text

It is a text of Scientific terminologies

The text of these documents are like this

```
RepID,Txt

1,K9G3P9 4H477 -Q207KL41 98464 ... Q207KL41
2,D84T8X4 -D9W4S2 -D9W4S2 8E8E65 ... D9W4S2 
3,-05L8NJ38 K2DD949 0W28DZ48 207441 ... K2D28K84
```

I can build a feature set using BOW algorithm

Here is my code

```
def BOW(df):
  CountVec = CountVectorizer() # to use only  bigrams ngram_range=(2,2)
  Count_data = CountVec.fit_transform(df)
  Count_data = Count_data.astype(np.uint8)
  cv_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(Count_data.toarray(), columns=CountVec.get_feature_names_out(), index=df.index)  # <- HERE
  return cv_dataframe.astype(np.uint8)

df_reps = pd.read_csv("c:\\file.csv")
df = BOW(df_reps["Txt"])
```

The result will be the count of words in the "**Txt**" column.

```
RepID K9G3P9  4H477 -Q207KL41 98464 ... Q207KL41
1     2       8     3         2     ... 1
2     0       1     2         4     ... 2
```

The trick and here where I need the help, is that some of these terms have a **-** ahead of it, and that should count as negative value

So if the a text have these values `Q207KL41 -Q207KL41 -Q207KL41`

in that case the terms that starts with - should be count as negative and therefore, the BOW for the `Q207KL41` is **-1**

instead of having a feature for `Q207KL41` and `-Q207KL41`
they both count towards the same term `Q207KL41` but with **positive and -negative**

so the dataset after BOW will look like this

```
RepID K9G3P9  4H477 Q207KL41 98464 ... 
1     2       8     -2         2     ...
2     0       1     0         4     ...
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably sufficiently different from normal bag of words vectorization that you'd be better off writing your own vectorizer. Here's the simplest approach I can come up with.

Code:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict


s = """
RepID,Txt
1,K9G3P9 4H477 -Q207KL41 98464 Q207KL41
2,D84T8X4 -D9W4S2 -D9W4S2 8E8E65 D9W4S2 
3,-05L8NJ38 K2DD949 0W28DZ48 207441 K2D28K84"""
df_reps = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))


def BOW(documents):
    ret = []
    vocabulary = defaultdict()
    vocabulary.default_factory = vocabulary.__len__
    for document in documents:
        feature_counter = defaultdict(int)
        for token in document.split():
            sign = 1
            if token[0] == "-":
                token = token[1:]
                sign = -1
            feature_idx = vocabulary[token]
            feature_counter[feature_idx] += sign
        ret.append(feature_counter)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ret)
    df = df.fillna(0)
    df.columns = vocabulary.keys()
    df = df.astype(np.int8)
    return df


print(BOW(df_reps["Txt"]))
```

Output:

```
   K9G3P9  4H477  Q207KL41  98464  D84T8X4  D9W4S2  8E8E65  05L8NJ38  K2DD949  0W28DZ48  207441  K2D28K84
0       1      1         0      1        0       0       0         0        0         0       0         0
1       0      0         0      0        1      -1       1         0        0         0       0         0
2       0      0         0      0        0       0       0        -1        1         1       1         1
```